# VS Code jsconfig.json does not seem to do anything

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a folder structure like so for a browser based JS project not using any modules or imports, as all files are just minified into one big file.

```
C:/project/lib
C:/project/src/js
```

In a file such as

```
C:/project/src/js/app.js
```

I do something like

```
const user = new User();
```

Which is from a file located in

```
C:/project/lib/user.js
```

I tried adding the jsconfig.json file but it doesn't do anything. I would love to just be able to ctrl click on `User` and go to that file.

Here is what I have, doesn't seem to do anything useful

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none",
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "include": [
        "./*",
        "./../../lib/*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file paths in exclude and include are relative to the location of jsconfig.json.

So you don't need ./ at the start of your path string

If you're looking for a shorthand for your relative path imports,
you can add the path options inside "CompilerOptions"